# Dynamically generated DataGrid the second click on CheckBox is not working in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, prism

**Problem 1**: I was facing well known problem with double click in dynamically generated DataGrid. I have first column with checkboxes. Two clicks were required to make the selection/deselection.
To resolve this issue I added following code.
Note: We have added Behavior class to handle everything related to DataGrid.

**Solution 1**:

```
xaml:
<DataGrid Name="MyDg" AutoGeneratedColumns="False" MouseLeftButtonUp="_MyGridRowLeftButtonUp" />

xaml.cs:

private void _MyGridRowLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if(MyDg.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == 0) //Making sure user clicked on first col, ignoring other cell clicks
   {
      ((MyViewModel)MyDg.SelectedItem).IsSelected = !((MyViewModel)MyDg.SelectedItem).IsSelected;
   }
}
```

So this solution is working and with single click I am able to select/deselect checkBoxes and underneath property is also getting set properly.
Note: Still it is not 100% perfect solution, since I am handling click on first column's cell not exactly from checkBox. If there is better solution for this then please suggest, probably I will not need following workarounds then.

**Problem 2**:
Since MouseLeftButtonUp event is directly on Grid, click anywhere on the grid is also processed. The real problem was if there is focus(selected) on particular cell(checkbox) and then user click anywhere else, that click is also treated as checkbox click.

**Solution 2**:
So I had to narrow down the clicking area/event. Hence added it only for Row, so only rowclick will be processed.

```
xaml:
<DataGrid Name="MyDg" AutoGeneratedColumns="False">
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="_MyGridRowLeftButtonUp"></EventSetter>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

So this was also working fine, until I discovered the following issue.

**Problem 3**:
I noticed that if I click same checkbox again, then on the second click the event it not firing however on the UI you see the effect, meaning you will see checkbox selected/deselected.
Looks like when there is fresh click (focus changes) on any checkbox first time then event is firing. If you click on another checkbox which was clicked earlier, this time also it is not firing.

- If I click on column header (sorting) then I guess some kind of refresh happens and then click works (again only for first time).

I have tried with PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp, which also gives same behavior. So is there any lost focus kind of event can be invoked after each click so that next click event fires for sure, or is there any other holistic solution to complete problem.
Appreciates help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include an example of an actual `CheckBox` in your question but if you use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` (instead of a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`) and bind the `IsChecked` property using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` the source property should get set immediately:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```